# setting up ssh for Jenkins to use at runtime

Tags: ssh, jenkins

I need some Jenkins jobs to have shell command line access to some other machines via ssh.

How can I do this?

I do not have the password of the target server[s], but I have a 'key' file, but when I run a job with the following

```
ssh -i /path/to/key/file name@someserver some_command
```

as a shell command, I get the following:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

ssh_askpass is a GUI utility which I nor the Jenkins user has access to.

I don't have the password to the Jenkins user (or whatever Jenkins runs as), so I cannot log in and create an ~/.ssh/id_dsa file.

What to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ssh is asking for password either because the key is not valid or the key is protected by a passphrase.

Try the key by running the same command yourself to find out which problem you need to solve.

If the key is protected by a passphrase, you should probably remove the passphrase because there is no good way to input the passphrase in a Jenkins job. You can do it with `ssh-keygen -p -f /path/to/key/file`. Set an empty passphrase to remove passphrase.

When you use ssh command in a non-interactive build job, you should probably use option `-o BatchMode=yes`. You might also want to use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, unless you can do the first login interactively and accept the host key.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. I used the following command line in the Jenkins job to execute this shell command:   ssh -i /path/to/key/file -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no theuser@$SOMEHOST some_command          (the hostname is parameterized.)

Comment: In my case the identity of the git server changes for some reason (yes, this is bad, but the server is hosted internally, so I assume our IT guys did something). ANYCASE, I had to assume the identity of the jenkins user, and the execute a git command. At that point I could I tell ssh to accept the remote server, and all was well.

Answer (score 3):

I had not installed the bin file ssh-askpass, so there is No such file or directory... I needed to install it.

Linux: sudo apt-get install ssh-askpass

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to ssh directly into the remote machine by putting the command in the "Execute Shell" field. 
Instead use the [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin) or [Publish Over SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin). You wont have to generate keys for the jenkins user. It will work out of the box.